# Optimsing image files in a responsive Bootstrap website for mobile desktop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I face an interesting issue with he following tool:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

I am testing the following website with the tool:

http://bestcastlesintown.co.uk/

Once the results are presenting the tool will issue the graphical assets in an optimized form with the following link text "Download optimized image, JavaScript, and CSS resources for this page."

I download these graphical assets (the .jpg) from the **mobile view** in PageSpeed insights tool and upload these to my server. The dimensions of these images are 450px by 290px as when being viewed in a mobile viewport.

[image]

However when I run the tool again in the **desktop view** for PageSpeed insights I am finding that the tool it is *still* telling me further image optimizations can be made to the .jpg files. Now when I find that when I "Download optimized image, JavaScript, and CSS resources for this page." - the graphical assets are dimensions 192px x 123px, as this is their size when viewed on a desktop viewport.

I know that this is a result of responsive web design techniques as image files resize with fluid CSS layouts, but is there an overall way to optimise the image for both viewports? The issue is the dynamic resizing as transitioning from desktop to mobile the reverse.

Comment: It's not really about pixel dimensions, but file size. Your rotating banner images are ~200KB, for example. They could easily be 25% of that.

Comment: Yes my initial though was to use a package like PhotoShop to lower the file size dramatically and make .jpg optimisations - by adjusting the quality etc.

Comment: In my experience it's best to use a pixel dimension that's 150-200% the size you expect to need with a JPG compression (quality) level of around 30-50%.

Comment: You'll find that browser scaling brings quality to acceptable levels, especially with the not-so-great photos you have there. http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/compressive-images.html

Comment: @isherwood can you just increase my understanding of browser scaling slightly? After reading that article, I am unsure as to whether that is a "default" example of how a typical web browser will handle an image - are images usually automatically scaled down by the browser? Surely as you have stated above, I still need to lower the quality of the 490px by 290px (in PhotoShop) before the image is scaled?

Comment: By "scaling" I simply mean the resizing for display that you described in your question. An image of fairly low quality looks clearer and sharper when displayed smaller than its actual size. A little experimentation will get you where you need to be. You don't have a massive display size range on your site, so I don't think loading different images for different devices is warranted.